# Throw error when any of the request parameter is missing/invalid

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have to accept a multipart form data consisting of JSON and multiple files and pass it to some third party APIs.

Currently, I have created a component as

```
@Component
public class Submit{
  private Multipart file;
  private String json;
  //getters setters
}
```

The controller looks like

```
 @Controller
 {
   //some code
   @PostMapping("/submit")
   public void post(@ModelAttribute @Valid Submit submit) throws Exception{
     getName()
   }
 }
```

When a request, not having all the parameters i.e. **file** & **json**, is made from Postman client to /submit API, Spring Boot doesn't seem to throw any kind of validation exception/bad request error.

Instead it proceeds with the `getName()` function.

How can I ensure that an exception is thrown if any of the parameter from the submit model is missing?

Shouldn't `@Valid` be the one responsible for making this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not doing any validation... You're saying that should be valid, but you're not saying what it should validate...

Comment: Agreed. @Notnull was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use annotations and [BindingResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html).
In your Submit Class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
public class Submit{
  @NotNull
  private Multipart file;
  @NotNull
  private String json;
  //getters setters
}
```

In post method You have to supply BindingResult.

```
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
@PostMapping("/submit")
public void post(@ModelAttribute @Valid Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
  if (bindingResult.hasFieldErrors()){
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    return;
  }
  getName()
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!!